# Runtime error after converting a micronaut project to micronaut servlet

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

I am trying to use Micronaut-servlet API for an existing microservice. 
Without the servlet API the following worked perfectly well

```
 @Test
  public void
  saved_movies_are_returned_in_my_list() {
    try (RxHttpClient client = embeddedServer.getApplicationContext()
        .createBean(RxHttpClient.class, embeddedServer.getURL())) {
      Movie movie = createMovie();
      Response<Movie> response = client.toBlocking().retrieve(
          HttpRequest.POST("/movies", movie).bearerAuth(idToken),
          Argument.of(Response.class, Movie.class));
      Response<List<Movie>> myMovies = client.toBlocking().retrieve(
          HttpRequest.GET("/movies").bearerAuth(idToken),
          Argument.of(Response.class, Argument.listOf(Movie.class)));
      assertThat(myMovies.data).contains(movie);
    }

  }
```

This is the controller

```
@Post("/")
  public Response<Movie> save(Movie movie) {
    return movieService.save(movie);
  }
```

And the service has logic where if the movie<->user mapping already exists then no data is saved and existing mapping is returned

```
public Response<Movie> save(Movie movie) {
    Optional<Movie> byUserIdAndTmdbId = movieRepository
        .findByUserIdAndTmdbId(movie.getUserId(), movie.getTmdbId());
    Response<Movie> movieResponse = null;
    if (!byUserIdAndTmdbId.isPresent()) {
      movieResponse = new Response<>("Movie Saved Successfully",
          State.SUCCESS, movieRepository.save(movie));
      return movieResponse;
    } else {
      return new Response<>("Movie already in list",
          State.SUCCESS, byUserIdAndTmdbId.get());
    }
  }
```

The repository is quite simple too

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends CrudRepository<Movie,Long> {
  List<Movie> findByUserId(String userId);
  Optional<Movie> getByUserIdAndTmdbId(String userId, Long timdbId);
}
```

All of this works perfectly fine until I remove

```
implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"
```

and replace it with 
`implementation("io.micronaut.servlet:micronaut-http-server-jetty:1.0.0.M1")`

I get the following exception after this change

```
Failed to convert argument [Movie] for value [io.micronaut.core.convert.value.ConvertibleValuesMap@17bae1ca] due to: Cannot convert an iterable with more than 1 value to a non collection object
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Failed to convert argument [Movie] for value [io.micronaut.core.convert.value.ConvertibleValuesMap@17bae1ca] due to: Cannot convert an iterable with more than 1 value to a non collection object
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1831)
```

And if I try to keep both the dependencies then I get duplicate bean exception for the HTTPClient injection!

Comment: You definitely cannot keep both dependencies

Comment: So what are my options? If I use Jetty or Tomcat dependency then I get `Cannot convert an iterable with more than 1 value to a non collection object` All my working test cases don't work as soon as I change the dependency!

Comment: Your options are to file an issue with an example so it can be fixed or debug the issue and submit a PR to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Add the `@Body` annotation to the controller method:

```
public Response<Movie> save(@Body Movie movie)
```

The default implementation (Netty runtime) does not need the annotation and thats why it works for netty, but if you use the servlet engine/implementation (jetty or tomcat etc) then the annotation is needed.

See: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-servlet/issues/243